# What is correct: widget.rowconfigure or widget.grid_rowconfigure?

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, tk-toolkit

When using grid geometry manager. Let's say you have:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk

root = tk.Tk()
root.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
root.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
ttk.Button(root, text="Hello World").grid(sticky=tk.NSEW)
root.mainloop()
```

The part where you specify the weight of the row/column can also be coded up as:

```
root.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
root.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
```

**For this example, what is correct method: widget.rowconfigure or widget.grid_rowconfigure? and why?**

Bonus: From an implementation POV, why do both work?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`widget.rowconfigure` is literally just an alias for `widget.grid_rowconfigure`. In the source code for tkinter is this line of code:

```
rowconfigure = grid_rowconfigure
```

I don't know for a fact, but I suspect that `widget.rowconfigure` was just added for convenience. Frankly, I didn't even know it existed until I read this question.

In my opinion, `grid_rowconfigure` is the proper name to use. I say that because tkinter is an interface to an underlying tcl/tk interpreter, and in tcl/tk the command is `grid rowconfigure`. Since most tkinter functions mirror the naming conventions of the tcl/tk functions as close as possible, `grid_rowconfigure` is the natural choice.

Comment: In my experience it's not very often that one would randomly create aliases for their functions especially in an API used by millions over many years. Given this experience, may there is/was a reason other than just convenience for the alias.

Comment: I guess `There should be one-- and preferably only one --obvious way to do it` has left the chat in this particular case

Answer (score 3):

If you browse Tkinter.py, you'll find that rowconfigure is just a reference to grid_rowconfigure.

Comment: You get the bonus points. I just hit F3 on the symbol and noticed that `rowconfigure=grid_rowconfigure`.