# Python tkinter widgets get resized uneven when user resizes the window

Tags: python, tkinter, resize

I am using a template that I saw in a youtube video for my app. I have split the window in 3 using 3 frames. All 3 frames are nested into a main frame. The main frame is attached directly to the root window.

I am using pack manager in order to place mainframe inside the root window.
I am using grid manager in order to place the 3 frames inside the mainframe.

The issue that I'm facing is that when I try to resize the window the left frame gets resized more than the other 2 frames, and I don't understand why that happens. I need the frames to resize proportionately to each other. Why is the left frame getting resized more than the others? and how can I correct this?

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk

Normal_Font = ('Verdana', 9)
Large_font = ('Verdana', 12)


class MainApp(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)

        mainframe = tk.Frame(self)
        mainframe.pack(side='top', fill='both', expand=True)
        mainframe.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        mainframe.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
        #mainframe.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky='nesw')

        #left frame
        employerframe = tk.Frame(mainframe)
        employerframe.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky='nesw')
        employerframe.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        employerframe.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1, uniform=1)
        label1 = tk.Label(employerframe, text='Employer Frame', font=Large_font)
        label1.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky='nesw')

        ttk.Separator(mainframe, orient=tk.VERTICAL) .grid(row=0, column=1, sticky='ns')

        #right frame
        candidateframe = tk.Frame(mainframe)
        candidateframe.grid(row=0, column=4, sticky='nesw')
        candidateframe.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        candidateframe.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1, uniform=1)
        label2 = tk.Label(candidateframe, text='Candidate Frame', font=Large_font)
        label2.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky='nesw')

        ttk.Separator(mainframe, orient=tk.VERTICAL) .grid(row=0, column=3, sticky='ns')

        #middle frame
        container = tk.Frame(mainframe)
        container.grid(row=0, column=2, sticky='nesw')
        container.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        container.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1, uniform=1)

        self.frames = {}
        frame = StartPage(container, self)
        self.frames[StartPage] = frame
        frame.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky='nesw')
        self.show_frame(StartPage)

    def show_frame(self, cont):
        frame = self.frames[cont]
        frame.tkraise()

class StartPage(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        label = tk.Label(self, text='Start Page', font=Large_font)
        label.pack(pady=10, padx=10)

app = MainApp()
app.mainloop()
```

Comment: It is because you have only set `weight` option of column 0 of `mainframe`.

Comment: Thank you very much,  you are right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because you are placing `employerframe`, `container`, `candidateframe` to `column=0`, `column=2`, `column=4`. But giving `weight=1` to only `column=0`. you have to add the following lines also to give column, 0, 2, 4 equal weight.

```
mainframe.grid_columnconfigure(2, weight=1)
mainframe.grid_columnconfigure(4, weight=1)
```

Try This:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk

Normal_Font = ('Verdana', 9)
Large_font = ('Verdana', 12)

class MainApp(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)

        mainframe = tk.Frame(self)
        mainframe.pack(side='top', fill='both', expand=True)
        mainframe.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        mainframe.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
        # ----- Added lines -----
        mainframe.grid_columnconfigure(2, weight=1)
        mainframe.grid_columnconfigure(4, weight=1)

        #left frame
        employerframe = tk.Frame(mainframe)
        employerframe.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky='nesw')
        label1 = tk.Label(employerframe, text='Employer Frame', font=Large_font)
        label1.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky='nesw')

        ttk.Separator(mainframe, orient=tk.VERTICAL) .grid(row=0, column=1, sticky='ns')

        #right frame
        candidateframe = tk.Frame(mainframe)
        candidateframe.grid(row=0, column=4, sticky='nesw')
        label2 = tk.Label(candidateframe, text='Candidate Frame', font=Large_font)
        label2.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky='nesw')

        ttk.Separator(mainframe, orient=tk.VERTICAL) .grid(row=0, column=3, sticky='ns')

        #middle frame
        container = tk.Frame(mainframe)
        container.grid(row=0, column=2, sticky='nesw')

        self.frames = {}
        frame = StartPage(container, self)
        self.frames[StartPage] = frame
        frame.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky='nesw')
        self.show_frame(StartPage)

    def show_frame(self, cont):
        frame = self.frames[cont]
        frame.tkraise()

class StartPage(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        label = tk.Label(self, text='Start Page', font=Large_font)
        label.pack(pady=10, padx=10)

app = MainApp()
app.mainloop()
```

Comment: Thank you so much, I knew there must be something obvious I was missing but for the life of me I couldn't place my finger on it. This works perfectly. I was afraid that this may have been some form of incompatibility between pack and grid. I've also seen the same thing done with Grid.rowconfigure(master, row, weight=1). Does this have the same functionality as master.grid_rowconfigure(row, weight=1)?

Comment: I think this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18280824/what-is-correct-widget-rowconfigure-or-widget-grid-rowconfigure) has your answer. :)